# GWTP - Clear Presenter Data

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

What is the recommended way to clear presenter data?  I would like to clear my UI on login.

As an example of the current problem, I have a NestedPresenter which is used to collect form data.  Someone can log out, then another user can log back in while the browser session is still active, and when the form is revealed the prior user's data is still showing.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It highly depends on the navigation you're using in your application. If you're using PlaceManager to navigate in-between almost stateless screens - overriding `onReset` method is the place I recommend you most, since each time navigation lands a user to the presenter - your clear code will be executed.

[Referring to documentation](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/core/presenters/lifecycle.html)

> onReset()
>
> This happens at the end of each user's navigation request. For example
>   if one needs to execute some code when user navigates to a presenter
>   that's already bound, already added to a Slot, this is the method that
>   needs to be overriden. Be careful though, this is called often, so
>   nothing too heavy should be executed in this method.

Clear your view, then fetch new model. If onReset is too frequent for you - stick with `onReveal()` then

> onReveal()
>
> onReveal() will be called when the Presenter is being revealed. In
>   GWTP's vocabulary, this means when a Presenter is added to a Slot
>   Therefore, it doesn't necessarily mean that the object will be visible
>   in the DOM. See this issue to understand the disambiguition. This
>   should be overriden when one wants to update something on the
>   Presenter when it's about to be added to a Slot.

and if onReveal does not work in your case somehow (you keep the presenters inserted in the slot all the time + navigation requests do not matter) - just clear info each time your presenter is hidden, via overriding `onHide()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It sounds to me like you are proposing some custom data clearing while hooking into the gwtp lifecycle at an appropriate time. My concern with that approach is its a maintenance headache and prone to errors. Every time I introduce new functionality, eg new data or conditionally displayed elements, I have the additional task of updating my custom clear data method.

Comment: Well, you put such a method in your View, and call it somewhere in presenter's lifecycle. There is no data-binding in GWTP afaik, so only you know what you populate in the view, when you set the model. What we usually do in these cases is: 1. create a method setModel(SomeJavaPojo model) {} in out View and ViewImpl, then, create another method clear() which may call setModel(new SomeJavaPojo()) to populate default values. Also, please keep in mind that onReset will be cascaded into the smaller PresenterWidgets of yours, so if your code is well-granulated - It won't be that complex to mantain